# VueX Getter to filter unique id's from array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, getter

I want to filter an array (that contains objects), to grab each message that contains a unique `correspondence_id`.

**Store contains 'messages' (with this structure):
[image]

**Getters** where I want to filter it.

```
getCorrespondedUsers: (state) => {
        return state.messages.unique
    }
```

The messages all contain a `correspondence_id`, however now I can only grab all the messages, but I want to just grab unique people. The purpose of this is that I have messages, but on the left I want to display each person that I've messaged (but I'm not sure how I can only display each person once).

How can I filter my messages to just return each message with a unique `correspondence_id`?

Comment: If you are using [Lodash](https://lodash.com) you can give a try with [_.uniqBy](https://lodash.com/docs#uniqBy)

Comment: @MarlonBarcarol Didn't realise I was using lodash, and it works perfectly thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lodash to maintain readability of your code. Example:

```
// don't forget to import only what
// you really need, not the whole library
import uniqBy from 'lodash/uniqBy'

export default {
  getCorrespondedUsers: state => uniqBy(state.messages, 'correspondence_id')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a [solution](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2016/05/removing-duplicate-objects-array-property-name-javascript/) of this problem.

So you can do this:

```
getCorrespondedUsers: (state) => {
        return state.messages.filter((obj, pos, arr) => {
           return arr.map(mapObj => mapObj["corresponde_id"]).indexOf(obj["corresponde_id"]) === pos;
    });
}
```

I tested [here](http://jsbin.com/zizawahahu/1/edit?js,console).

I hope it works!